# What does "Arg = Exploded" mean in Swift crash log?

Tags: swift, crash-log

I get a crash log from Crashlytics/Fabric which reads like the following:

```
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of
MyClass.viewWillAppear (MyClass)(Swift.Bool) -> ()
```

what does exploded mean for Arg[0]? It's weird that there are two arguments because we're talking about `viewWillAppear` here - is the first argument the object itself?

Comment: I had the same report this morning, did u know the reason ??

Comment: no, unfortunately I don't know anything about this yet

Comment: In my case this crash happens only on physical iPhone 5 device (but simulator and other devices works) so I guess it's a bug in swift so I changed the code to get the same results. My code was splitting a string to get an array of x and y values then convert them to `CGFloat` then use them in `CGRectMake()` and its magically fixed.

Comment: I have this problem too. I have never been able to reproduce this myself, I only see some of my users getting it. Let us know if you work out what it is. @EwanMellor - I believe that is different. I don't have the 'Dead' part at least.

Comment: @Robert It's entirely benign and does not affect you.  The only thing you have to pay attention to is the trace itself, not what Swift marks those arguments with.  Take a look at my answer in the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue a week ago, and thankfully managed to fix it remotely. I believe it is a parsing issue.

The issue was because I was getting an array of strings from the server, and one of the argument was empty, generating a parsing error of the arguments

`["String1", "String2", "String3",]`

should have been

`["String1", "String2", "String3"]`

In your case : Look for what is in your viewWillAppear and check for any parsing/serializing. A bad object returned is probably the root cause of this