# Swift owned to guaranteed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I just found 5 crash reports inside the xcode organizer. When I open them I get this stacktrace (marked area is the name of my app):

[image]

This error occurs on iOS8.4 as well as on iOS9, and on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 devices likewise.

It is hard for me to track down because I cannot reproduce it neither on iPhone5(8.4) nor on iPhone6(9.0.1).

1./2. somewhere here:

```
override func onButtonTableViewCellClick(button: BfPaperButton) {}
```

3.

```
var button: BfPaperButton = BfPaperButton.newAutoLayoutView()

func onClick() {
    delegate?.onButtonTableViewCellClick(button) // 3
}
```

I use swift 2, xcode 7 and iOS9. Help me to understand the error. What does the first line with the red image mean? Why has this error something to do with `Swift.String` at all??

I found this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6078 where I extracted this information:

> One case I've seen of this kind of crash is when an Obj-C-based object
>   calls a delegate method that's Swift-based, and a parameter value is
>   nil but the Swift method signature isn't an optional type.   In the
>   case I saw, it was an error in the bridged delegate method signature —
>   it was actually supposed to be optional.   It could be something
>   similar in your case (the Swift definition doesn't allow for an
>   optional when it should), or it could be a bug in the Obj-C code
>   (producing nil when it shouldn't).

I use a obj-c lib called BfPaperButton which creates a Button that looks like in android material design. Maybe the error is related to this library?

Log:

[image]

View image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aQ8m.png

I have two string extensions. One for length and one for substring:

```
extension String {

    var length: Int { return self.characters.count }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return String(Array(self.characters)[i])
    }

    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex)
        let end = startIndex.advancedBy(r.endIndex)
        return substringWithRange(Range(start: start, end: end))
    }
}
```

Line 188 is:

```
NSUUID().UUIDString[0...4]
```

which uses substring extension. Maybe the error is here?

```
override func onButtonTableViewCellClick(button: UIButton) {

        if let title = button.titleLabel?.text {

            if title == "Send code" {

                tmpPhoneNumber = ""

                var tmp = phoneNumber

                if tmp.length > 1 {
                    if tmp[0] == "0" {
                        tmp = tmp[1...tmp.characters.count - 1]
                    }

                    tmpPhoneNumber = "0049" + tmp
                    phoneNumberWithCode = tmpPhoneNumber
                    sendAlert(tmp)
                } else {
                    PfToast.showError("Please enter your phone number.")
                }

            } else if title == "Finish" {
                if let cell: InputTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 2)) as? InputTableViewCell {
                    if isLicenceValid(cell.inputField.inputField.text!) {
                        createCustomer(cell.inputField.inputField.text!)
                    } else {
                        PfToast.showError("Please enter correct licence plate.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual error message though inside the log viewer?

Comment: @l'L'l What do you mean? I have the organizer view (see my updated question) and when I click on "Open in project" I get the log view like seen in the first picture.

Comment: Can you post the entire text of `thread 0, #1` (blanking out private info is fine, it's just that the rest of the line is trucated - which might include the line in which the error occurs).

Comment: @l'L'l see my update (Sadly xcode does not allow to copy logs :/)

Comment: I have a feeling it's the optional value that is associated with the `onclick()` function returning nil thus causing the exception. One more question, what is on line 188?

Comment: @l'L'l see my update

Comment: Unfortunately it's difficult to tell what exactly is causing it without the actual exception message; crash stacks can only reveal so much. Setting up "symbolicating" can help with this type of thing tenfold — [see this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports), as you can get the specifics.

Comment: You might want to NSLog the result of `UUIDString`, and possibly the substring function to see if it ever returns nil (the exception `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value` is commonly associated with the issue you have)

Comment: @l'L'l I will check this out, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Are you sure you haven't fixed the bug already? How old are the logs? That `tmp[0]` seems to be the only possibility for the crash but you are handling the `tmp.length == 0` case correctly so I can't imagine how the crash could happen with the current code.

Comment: `onButtonTableViewCellClick` is overridable, is the one your paste here  the one in the `VerificationController`?

Comment: What is on line 168? Is it perhaps `tmp = tmp[1...tmp.characters.count - 1]`?

Comment: Can you add the code around line 188?

Comment: The 168 and 188 are irrelevant. Those are machine code offsets, not line numbers. We can tell from stack trace that your crash is in `subscript (i: Int) -> String`, called from `onButtonTableViewCellClick`. The only use of that `subcript` in that caller is the line `if tmp[0] == "0" {`. Is it possible that your string starts with a "funny" Unicode character that is represented by a surrogate pair?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion, you are looking at wrong places. When I am looking at the logs, what I see is:

1. A click on a button
2. `onButtonTableViewCellClick`
3. Obj-C to Swift internals (you can learn more in [What's Dead & Exploded in Swift's exception stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764669/whats-dead-exploded-in-swifts-exception-stack))
4. Indexing `String` by `Int` (see `String.subscript.getter (Swift.Int) -> String`)

We can be sure that the crash happened somewhere here:

```
return String(Array(self.characters)[i])
```

I think we can rule out `nil` because that would cause an earlier crash. Most likely you have an **character index out of bounds** problem. That means `i` is either negative or higher than `length - 1` (maybe you are indexing an empty text?)

Unfortunately, the important code is in `onButtonTableViewCellClick` and you haven't posted that.

Comment: Thanks! I added some code to my question. Does it help?