# In App Purchase causes occasional crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash, in-app-purchase, crash-reports

I've searched the internet for help on this but to no avail. My app is live on the app store and a minority of users are reporting the app freezing on them and crashing after making an In App Purchase (the only IAP in my game, it basically unlocks the full version). Even when they restart their device and try to continue, it crashes again. I haven't been able to reproduce the crash - here is the crash report:

```
{"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 9.2 (13C75)","timestamp":"2015-12-12 15:34:59.59 +0000","build_version":"1","app_name":"MyApp","bundleID":"com.MyName.MyApp","name":"MyApp","is_first_party":false,"app_version":"1.0","share_with_app_devs":true,"slice_uuid":"7abb6a6c-91be-3da0-af0f-2cc21f9a6b83","adam_id":1021569826}
Incident Identifier: 59B078E3-ABC9-47C7-A3BE-6311BBB968F6
CrashReporter Key:   b30d57098eecd5a7dfcd44f3a04cfb01bdef557f
Hardware Model:      iPad2,5
Process:             MyApp [977]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EFAB47F6-F1A3-42A4-A6F1-8A038932ED86/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.MyName.MyApp
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-12-12 15:34:59.59 +0000
Launch Time:         2015-12-12 15:30:02.02 +0000
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                       0x001f8cb8 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead and Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of MyApp.IAPHelper.paymentQueue (MyApp.IAPHelper)(__ObjC.SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions : [__ObjC.SKPaymentTransaction]) -> () (IAPHelper.swift:0)
1   MyApp                       0x001f59a8 @objc MyApp.IAPHelper.paymentQueue (MyApp.IAPHelper)(__ObjC.SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions : [__ObjC.SKPaymentTransaction]) -> () (IAPHelper.swift:0)
2   StoreKit                        0x2e7c1a80 __NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 82
3   CoreFoundation                  0x25464630 CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
4   StoreKit                        0x2e7c1a1c -[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutChanges:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 126
5   StoreKit                        0x2e7c2318 -[SKPaymentQueue _processUpdates:trimUnmatched:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 1042
6   StoreKit                        0x2e7c2ca6 -[SKPaymentQueue _updatePaymentsForMessage:] + 120
7   StoreKit                        0x2e7c1938 __44-[SKPaymentQueue _handleMessage:connection:]_block_invoke + 142
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x250c9b5a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x250c9b46 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x250d7ee0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1522
11  CoreFoundation                  0x255133fc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 6
12  CoreFoundation                  0x255118f6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
13  CoreFoundation                  0x25464bf8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
14  CoreFoundation                  0x254649e4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
15  GraphicsServices                0x266b0ac8 GSEventRunModal + 158
16  UIKit                           0x296f4ba0 UIApplicationMain + 142
17  MyApp                       0x0018bc24 main (AppDelegate.swift:12)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x25113872 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x251e6320 kevent_qos + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x250de098 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 254
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x250dddf6 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 36

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x251d0c24 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x251d0a28 mach_msg + 38
2   CoreFoundation                  0x25513354 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 134
3   CoreFoundation                  0x255116dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1034
4   CoreFoundation                  0x25464bf8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x254649e4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
6   CFNetwork                       0x25aa781e +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 484
7   Foundation                      0x25d69164 __NSThread__start__ + 1146
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2528985a _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x252897ce _pthread_start + 108
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25287724 thread_start + 6

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x251e4f14 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x255187a2 __CFSocketManager + 564
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2528985a _pthread_body + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x252897ce _pthread_start + 108
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25287724 thread_start + 6

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x251e588c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25287b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25287718 start_wqthread + 6

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x251e588c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25287b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25287718 start_wqthread + 6

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x251e588c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25287b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25287718 start_wqthread + 6

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x3bc6d0b0      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x17222bc2      r6: 0x15ea4330      r7: 0x003fdaf0
r8: 0x1736bce0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x003fdbcc     r11: 0xffffffff
ip: 0xf6535949    sp: 0x003fd934      lr: 0x001f7478      pc: 0x001f8cb8
cpsr: 0x60000010

Binary Images:
<not included for reasons of brevity>
```

The method referenced as causing the crash is as follows:

```
public func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
 for transaction in transactions {
  switch (transaction.transactionState) {
  case .Purchased:
    completeTransaction(transaction)
    break
  case .Failed:
    failedTransaction(transaction)
    break
  case .Restored:
    restoreTransaction(transaction)
    break
  case .Deferred:
    break
  case .Purchasing:
    break
  }
 }
}
```

I'm not sure where to begin really as the code in `paymentQueue: updatedTransactions` looks ok to me and was in fact taken direct from a Ray Wenderlich tutorial on IAPs: http://www.raywenderlich.com/105365/in-app-purchases-tutorial-getting-started

This in particular is puzzling me:
`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead and Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed>` What does that mean?

Anybody have any ideas? Or advice on how to reproduce the crash? Because it's only happened a handful of times, could it be something to do with the user's device or Apple's IAP handling, or is it definitely my code?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

In response to Alpesh's answer, my function now looks like this:

```
public func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
  let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
  dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    for transaction in transactions {
      switch (transaction.transactionState) {
      case .Purchased:
        self.completeTransaction(transaction)
        break
      case .Failed:
        self.failedTransaction(transaction)
        break
      case .Restored:
        self.restoreTransaction(transaction)
        break
      case .Deferred:
        break
      case .Purchasing:
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Explanation of `Dead` and `Owned To Guaranteed`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30764669/558933. Also, what are the `break` statements for (`case` statements in Swift do not fall through)?

Comment: Thanks for the link RoboticCat. I'm not sure why the break statements are needed - as I said, I followed this tutorial and that's how it was done there: http://www.raywenderlich.com/105365/in-app-purchases-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the crash because of the memory issue. I think you putto code like this after some delay it works batter. you can also use GCD Dispatch Timer

public func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                for transaction in transactions {
  switch (transaction.transactionState) {
  case .Purchased:
    completeTransaction(transaction)
    break
  case .Failed:
    failedTransaction(transaction)
    break
  case .Restored:
    restoreTransaction(transaction)
    break
  case .Deferred:
    break
  case .Purchasing:
    break
  }
 }
```

}
}

Comment: Thanks Alpesh. I have edited my question to show the function (Xcode prompted me to put 'self' before some function calls). So dispatch_after makes a slight delay, how does that help? (I am keen to learn!)

Comment: I will test the new code and if it works I'll mark the question as correct, but bear in mind I won't know if it works until I submit an update to Apple! I'll remember to come back here and mark it correct though. :)

Comment: Alpesh, FYI while the issue is fixed for new users, those who experienced a crash in version 1.0 are still having issues even with the new version. I made a question about it here: stackoverflow.com/questions/35814267/in-app-purchase-bug-now-fixed-but-still-crashing-for-previously-affected-users

Comment: I just received a crash report from a user whose device crashed when making an IAP, which suggests the initial problem has indeed not been fixed. :-( Admittedly the number of these crashes has reduced dramatically in the updated version, but it looks as though the underlying problem is still there. I will make a new question about this providing more detail.